# Configure GWT compiler to use less memory?

Tags: maven, gwt, memory, compiler-construction

I am trying to build a large Maven-GWT project on a virtual host, which has a limit amount of RAM and cannot use swap space.

The GWT compile stage (where it computes permutations) uses a massive amount of the CPU and memory, and I was wondering if there was any way I could impose a limit on how much of each it uses, even if it takes much longer to compile.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the maven-gwt-plugin?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using more than one worker thread, decrease it to just one worker thread - that will decrease the memory required. however, the compile will be correspondingly slower. Otherwise, there isn't much you can do to decrease the memory requirements. Setting the xmx to a lower number will work too, but that will cause OOME if it is too low. i think about 256m is the minimum, tho 128m works for most projects of a small to medium size.

add `-Dgwt-plugin.localWorkers="1"` and `-Dgwt-plugin.extraJvmArgs="-Xmx128m -Xms16m"` to your `MAVEN_OPTS`, and tweak those numbers till it works nicely.